# deleting node from xml at specific position

Tags: java, xpath, jaxp

I have XML like below:

```
<As>
<a>
    <Bs>
        <b>5</b>
    <Bs>
</a>
<a>
    <Bs>
        <b>9</b>
    <Bs>
</a>
<a></a>
<a>
    <Bs>
        <b>12</b>
        <b>14</b>
        <b>15</b>
    </Bs>
</a>
```

Now I want to delete node selected row. Say user has selected node `<b>14</b>`.

I have generated expression as:

```
String expression  =  "/As/a[4]/Bs/b[2]";
Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
```

It is giving Following exception:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens: 'health-history-questions', '/', 'health-history-question', '[', '3', ']'
at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.error(XPathParser.java:610)
at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:145)
at org.apache.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:178)
at org.apache.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:266)
at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:195)
at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:281)
```

Comment: Without showing your *actual* XML and your *actual* XPath or XSLT, showing the exception does not help at all.

Comment: Judging by the exception, you are not showing us the same input you ran the program with. Either show us that input or run the program with your example input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry Guys problem was .. the expression form has missing '/' . So my mistake. I apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Why use such a complicated XPath? Try this one

```
String expression = "//b[.=14]";
```

or, if you must check the correct hierarchy, this one:

```
String expression = "/As/a/Bs/b[.=14]";
```